# timer signature in setTimeout in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, settimeout

**What would be the *correct way* to get the Nodejs timer signature?**

Browsers returns integers, but NodeJS returns an internal object which doesn't seem to have a property or method with a parse-able string or number. Is there any way to get this?

Given the following code:

```
var x = setTimeout(()=>{},1);
```

`console.log(x);` in NodeJS returns:

```
Timeout {
  _called: false,
  _idleTimeout: 1,
  _idlePrev: [TimersList],
  _idleNext: [TimersList],
  _idleStart: 2275,
  _onTimeout: [Function],
  _timerArgs: undefined,
  _repeat: null,
  _destroyed: false,
  domain: [Domain],
  [Symbol(unrefed)]: false,
  [Symbol(asyncId)]: 73,
  [Symbol(triggerId)]: 5 }
```

while browsers returns (almost random) integers like `3`

Comment: Hi @blagus, What is the goal here, i mean what do u wanna do?

Comment: Get the unique timmer id, not as object but as integer, string or similar serializable identifiable key.

Comment: Why do you need to get the unique timer id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So hi again @blagus,

Your answer actually lives on the docs. Here you can see the [referance](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_timeout_symbol_toprimitive) from nodejs docs which called `Symbol.toPrimitive`;

```js
const timer = setTimeout(() => {}, 100);
const timerID = timer[Symbol.toPrimitive]();

clearTimeout(timerID); // you can use this directly on clearTimeout to clear or
// clearTimeout(timer); // just use timer itself =)
console.log(timer[Symbol.toPrimitive]()); // give's you a serializable id which is a number bdw :)
console.log(timer);
```

Comment: `Symbol.toPrimitive` is something new for me. Thank you very so much!

Answer (score 0):

try this solution:

```
let timerId: ReturnType<typeof setTimeout>
```

Details:
in a browser, the timer identifier is a number. In other environments, this can be something else. For instance, Node.js returns a timer object with additional methods.

ref: the last paragraph before [setInterval](https://javascript.info/settimeout-setinterval#setinterval) section